# Install PyCharm IDE from repo (without wget)

Tags: python, packaging, ide

Is there a way to install the PyCharm IDE (community version) from a repo (without wget).

I think the wget method found in many blogs is too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a third-party packaged **.DEB**:
[Here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/utopic/apps/getdeb/pycharm)

But the simplest way would be to use [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) utility. It is in the repos in recent versions. Then just run

```
umake ide pycharm
```

It will ask a few questions and install recent ide for you. Will not manage autoupdates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading it from their website?

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/

If wget is too complicated, I doubt using git clone is going to be any easier.